# loop through rows and INSERT INTO SELECT from the same table

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in SQL-Server2012, that will update some rows, then re-insert them again into the same table but with NULLs or different calculated values.

my table 'schedule':

```
CREATE TABLE [cil].[schedule](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[taskFK] [int] NULL,
[scheduledDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[completionDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[rotaCycle] [smallint] NULL,
[result] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_schedule] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

my table 'task':

```
CREATE TABLE [cil].[task](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[standard] [varchar](250) NULL,
[equipFK] [int] NULL,
[areaFK] [smallint] NULL,
```

CONSTRAINT [PK_task] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

existing stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [cil].[updateCompletionDate]
@equipID int,
@myCompletionDate datetime

AS   
UPDATE cil.schedule SET completionDate=@myCompletionDate
WHERE schedule.id IN (
SELECT schedule.id 
FROM cil.schedule
LEFT JOIN cil.task
ON cil.schedule.taskFK=cil.task.id
WHERE CAST(scheduledDate AS DATE)<=CAST(GetDate() AS DATE)
AND completionDate IS NULL
AND result IS NOT NULL
AND equipFK=@equipID);
GO
```

and now I want to add the RE-INSERT to the above SP:

```
INSERT INTO cil.schedule (taskFK, scheduledDate, rotaCycle) 
SELECT taskFK, scheduledDate = DATEADD(dd, (SELECT rotaCycle FROM 
cil.schedule WHERE id=??),scheduledDate), rotaCycle
FROM cil.schedule LEFT JOIN cil.task ON task.id=schedule.taskFK
WHERE completionDate=@myCompletionDate
AND task.equipFK=@equipID;
```

Dont know how to loop through all ID from 1st part of the SP?

Comment: you'd have to maybe select them into a temp table or something

Comment: Add an [`OUTPUT...INTO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) clause to your update statement to insert the modified rows into the same table but with different values as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my procedure, cursor loops through and re-inserts modified correctly data:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [cil].[addComplDateAnd_ReSchedule]

@equipID int,
@myCompletionDate datetime2(6)

AS   
/* add completion date */

UPDATE cil.schedule SET completionDate=@myCompletionDate
WHERE schedule.id IN (
                    SELECT schedule.id 
                    FROM cil.schedule
                    LEFT JOIN cil.task ON cil.schedule.taskFK=cil.task.id
                    WHERE CAST(scheduledDate AS DATE)<=CAST(GetDate() AS DATE)
                    AND completionDate IS NULL
                    AND result IS NOT NULL
                    AND equipFK=@equipID);

/* reschedule tasks */

DECLARE @nextTaskID AS INT;
DECLARE @nextScheduledDate AS DATETIME2(6);
DECLARE @nextRotaCycle AS INT;

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT taskFK, scheduledDate, rotaCycle
FROM cil.schedule 
LEFT JOIN cil.task ON cil.schedule.taskFK=cil.task.id
WHERE completionDate=@myCompletionDate
AND equipFK=@equipID;

OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @nextTaskID, @nextScheduledDate, @nextRotaCycle;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
   --Do stuff with scalar values
   INSERT INTO cil.schedule (taskFK, scheduledDate, rotaCycle)
        VALUES(@nextTaskID
            ,DATEADD(dd, @nextRotaCycle, @nextScheduledDate)
            ,@nextRotaCycle)

   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @nextTaskID, @nextScheduledDate, 
@nextRotaCycle;
END;
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using output clause and delete table. i have created below pseudo code to give you some idea how this will work -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [cil].[updateCompletionDate]
@equipID int,
@myCompletionDate datetime

AS   

DECLARE @MyTable table(  
    id int ,   
    taskFK int 
    ....  ); -- declare all required columns   

UPDATE cil.schedule SET completionDate=@myCompletionDate 
OUTPUT deleted.id,  
       deleted.taskFK -- list of required columns you want 
INTO @MyTable
WHERE schedule.id IN (
SELECT schedule.id 
FROM cil.schedule
LEFT JOIN cil.task
ON cil.schedule.taskFK=cil.task.id
WHERE CAST(scheduledDate AS DATE)<=CAST(GetDate() AS DATE)
AND completionDate IS NULL
AND result IS NOT NULL
AND equipFK=@equipID)


INSERT INTO cil.schedule (taskFK, scheduledDate, rotaCycle) 
select [required coluns] 
from @MyTableVa join cil.schedule -- all requied join conditions
```

Comment: yes i will update your real table and insert old values into @mytable

Comment: I dont like this method, How to do it  using CURSOR, as I need different values in one column when re-INSERTing

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL Output clause](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/output-clause-sample-code-with-insert-update-delete-sql-server-2005.aspx) to update your table and insert effected rows into the same table

Please check following simple sample script

```
/*
create table OutputClauseSample (
Id int identity(1,1),
Code varchar(10),
Val int
)
insert into OutputClauseSample select 'A',10
insert into OutputClauseSample select 'B',20
insert into OutputClauseSample select 'C',30
*/
update OutputClauseSample
set Val = 2 * Val
output (deleted.Code)
into OutputClauseSample (Code)
where id = 3

select * from OutputClauseSample
```